# Nightwatch inside Docker only works with Phantom

Tags: selenium, docker, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I am running a suite of tests with nightwatch.js inside a Docker container.

When I run the tests with Phantomjs, they work perfectly.  When I run the same tests using Chrome or Firefox, I get a "connection reset" error.

The base image for the Docker container is Ubuntu:16.04, I have xvfb installed and running.

I have applied the various tricks to counter the known errors when attempting to run a headless Chrome inside docker, including:

- running the container with --privileged
- running the container with --net=host
- running the container with -v /var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus
- running it with -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm
- setting the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null environment variable
- making sure that chrome is running with the "--no-sandbox" argument and the "--disable-gpu" arguments

The thing is, both Firefox and chrome are actually running, (you see they can both take screenshots) - the problem is just the "connection reset" error.

**Why do I get a connection reset error from Chrome and Firefox when Phantom can run the tests perfectly?**

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the Dockerfile?

Comment: I can't post the Dockerfile, but I've found the answer (literally a couple of days ago) and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, I had to set the "no_proxy" environment variable inside docker and set it's value to localhost

```
ENV no_proxy "localhost;127.0.0.1"
```